# How to check if user has permissions to create specific object

Tags: query, permissions, soap

Given User.Id, how do I check with SOAP if this user has permission to create Contact or Lead?

Update:
So far I've discovered only this solution:

```
SELECT ProfileId FROM User WHERE Id='0056g000002TnrpAAC'

SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE ProfileId='00e6g000000mn74AAA' // This we will use as ParentId in next query

SELECT PermissionsCreate FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE ParentId = '0PS6g000004cEH7GAM' AND SobjectType='Lead'
```

Is it possible to do it with one or two queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `createable` property of `DescribeGlobalSObjectResult` to verify whether the current user has read, create, or update access to an sObject, respectively. 
From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal_describeglobalresult.htm)

> `DescribeGlobalSObjectResult` represents the properties for one of the
>   objects available for your org.

Comment: I think the question is about getting CRUD for specific user id (not only running) and by using SOAP API, not Apex.

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrBerehovskyi, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE ParentId in (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE
AssigneeId ='0056g000002TnrpAAC') AND SobjectType='Lead'
```

where AssigneeId is User.Id